# Cant execute tcl script due to line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Tags: tcl

Attached is my code . However when i execute it ,this error message come out :line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Since i am new to tcl , i dont know where is going wrong. please help !!! Many thanks

```
 set filename "a.qip"
 set temp [create_temp_file a.qip]
 set out [open $temp w]
 set in [open $filename r]
 set entityname "edward"

 while {[gets $in line] != -1} {
       if {[string match "*SDC_FILE*" $line]} {
        puts $out $line
        puts $out "set variant_name $entityname"
     } else {
          puts $out $line
     }
 }
    close $in
    close $out 

file link -hard $filename a.qip.bak
file rename -force $temp $filename
```

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to use `sh` to interpret your Tcl file:

```
$ sh f.tcl
f.tcl: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
f.tcl: line 11: `     } else {'
```

You need to use `tclsh`

```
$ tclsh f.tcl
invalid command name "create_temp_file"
    while executing
"create_temp_file a.qip"
    invoked from within
"set temp [create_temp_file a.qip]"
    (file "f.tcl" line 2)
```

Comment: Sorry for posting a silly comment, but good catch indeed, enjoyed it!

Answer (score 0):

If your file a.qip contains specific char like curlies '{' and '}', it will be misinterpreted by the string match.

Comment: Not true: `set line "with {braces} { SDC_FILE ..."; if {[string match "*SDC_FILE*" $line]} {puts OK}`

Comment: yes, you are right. I had a similar issue but it was with lindex usage.

Comment: Tcl won't evaluate the contents of a variable unless you explicitly ask it to. Were you using `eval` or `uplevel`?